# How can as.Date() convert fully written dates into ISO 8601?

Tags: r, as.date

I currently have a vector of dates that are in the following format:

`a <- c("Wednesday 26th May 2021","Thursday 27th May 2021")`

I've tried to get it into ISO 8601 using the following:

`as.Date(a, "%I %d%S %F %Y")`

But I'm not 100% certain about the syntax of writing dates.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the date suffixes and use `as.Date` -

```
#Added an extra date that does not have th as prefix.
a <- c("Wednesday 26th May 2021","Thursday 27th May 2021", 
       'Tuesday 1st June 2021', 'Monday 31st May 2021')

as.Date(sub('(?<=\\d)(th|rd|st|nd)', '', a, perl = TRUE), '%A %d %b %Y')
#[1] "2021-05-26" "2021-05-27" "2021-06-01" "2021-05-31"
```

Read `?strptime` for different format specification.

---

If you are open to packages `lubridate::dmy` works directly.

```
lubridate::dmy(a)
#[1] "2021-05-26" "2021-05-27" "2021-06-01" "2021-05-31"
```

Comment: Ronak, can it's opposite be done directly i.e. without using regex.  I mean adding st/th/rd to dates

Comment: I am not aware of a function that does it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the `sub('th|rd|st|nd', '', a)` unfortunately messes up Monday by turning it into Moay though.

Comment: The `lubridate::dmy` one works like a dream though, thanks!

Comment: @timnus Yes, I did not notice that. Maybe we need a stricter regex. Updated the answer with that.